# Background padding (inset drawable) not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html) InsetDrawables can be used to make backgrounds smaller than the View that contains it. However when I do this all my child views (ImageView, TextView) align with the bottom border of the inset background. Any idea how I can achieve this effect?

Btw: FrameLayouts don't work either for devices with Android 2.x because margins are handled differently.

Comment: _FrameLayouts don't work either for devices with Android 2.x because margins are handled differently._ - this is the first time i'm hearing this. Any source about this?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this would be to have two linearlayouts inside relativelayout: 1. used for background (orientation:vertical, top green, bottom gray) and 2. for imageview and text (horizontal, first item imageview, second text). 1. linearlayout fills relativelayout match_parent and 2. linearlayout has layout_marginTop="distance form top" and layout_marginLeft="distance from left".